# Automated script or program for copying and renaming a file

Tags: windows, shell, automation, file-rename

I would like to have a script or maybe some kind of program that is monitoring selected file, and when the date of a file changes(file gets updated every hour), this script copies this file to another folder and renames it at the same time. But needs to overwrite the old one.

For example. File aaa.dat gets updated, script recognizes change, moves file to desired folder, renames file to bbb.dat, overwrite the old bbb.dat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [entr](http://eradman.com/entrproject/) to achive this.

```
 <<<"aaa.dat" entr cp -f \_ dest_path/bbb.dat
```

`cp` will overwrite `bbb.dat` file in `dest_path`

Comment: I am using Microsoft Windows

Comment: Oh, you mentioned bash in tags before edit. I can't help with windows